# TPL not producing right results with Parallel.For and List<T>

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have a simple program that returns the sum of prime numbers below a certain number.

When I run that program without using TPL, it gives correct results, but when I run the program using TPL it gives incorrect results.

I cannot understand what is the problem with this. Can anybody help?

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var executionStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfPrimesBelowviaTPL(2000000));
    Console.WriteLine("End Time: " + (DateTime.Now - executionStartTime).ToString("T"));
    var a = Console.ReadLine();
}

private static long GetSumOfPrimesBelow(int number)
{
    long sumOfPrimes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if ((i == 2 || i % 2 != 0) && (i == 3 || i % 3 != 0) && IsPrime(i))
        {
            sumOfPrimes += i;
        }
    }
    return sumOfPrimes;
}

private static long GetSumOfPrimesBelowviaTPL(int number)
{
    long sumOfPrimes = 0;
    var primeNumbersList = new List<int>();
    Parallel.For(2, number, i =>
    {
        if ((i == 2 || i % 2 != 0) && (i == 3 || i % 3 != 0) && IsPrime(i))
        {
            primeNumbersList.Add(i);
        }
    });
    foreach (var item in primeNumbersList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        sumOfPrimes += item;
    }
    return sumOfPrimes;
}
```

Comment: Regular list is not thread safe and you're adding items to one from (possibly) multiple threads. You'll either need locking, a concurrent collection or - even better - PLINQ.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Can you suggest how to implement PLINQ in this particular case or may be a link on how to use PLinq in such scenarios. I can only find links for Linq 2 Sql for PLinq

Comment: There you go: `ParallelEnumerable.Range(2, number - 2).Where(x => (x == 2 || x % 2 != 0) && (x == 3 || x % 3 != 0) && IsPrime(x)).Sum();`

Comment: Thanks @PatrykĆwiek, but the problem with above code is that it accepts a range of integers and returns the sum as an integer as well, which is not in my case. because the range is huge and the result would definitely will be a long (at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are facing is something called as a producer-consumer problem. Also the list type is not thread safe.

Not very sure if this will solve your problem so please try it out and let me know.

1. In your GetSumOfPrimesBelowviaTPL method, instead of List use BlockingCollection. So your primeNumbersList will not be a List type but a BlockingCollection type. This will ensure thread safety. Also it is more efficient than the custom locking construct.
2. Before foreach write primeNumbersList.CompleteAdding(). This will solve your producer-consumer problem.
3. In the foreach, instead of using primeNumbersList directly, use primeNumbersList.GetConsumingEnumerable().

So your method should be something like this.

```
private static long GetSumOfPrimesBelowviaTPL(int number)
{
    long sumOfPrimes = 0;
    var primeNumbersList = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    Parallel.For(2, number, i =>
    {
        if ((i == 2 || i % 2 != 0) && (i == 3 || i % 3 != 0) && IsPrime(i))
        {
            primeNumbersList.Add(i);
        }
    });

    primeNumbersList.CompleteAdding();

    foreach (var item in primeNumbersList.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        sumOfPrimes += item;
    }
    return sumOfPrimes;
}
```

Obviously you would need to include a few namespaces. I have not tested this method on my side so please pardon me if there are any compilation errors.

Comment: I have used your code and it works like a charm :)
Thanks for all your time. I will mark your answer as correct, because it gave more insight into the TPL by using some built in classes rather than implementing custom locking :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Parallel.For, you want to have something like this

```
lock (primeNumbersList)
{
      primeNumbersList.Add(i);
}
```

Then it will produce the same result. List isn't thread friendly, and writing to list like that can cause trouble.

Also I noticed, your algorithm seems not very efficient, why loop twice, if you can just calculate your sum inside your Prallel.For

Comment: I looped twice because the sum variable will be modified by two or more threads and it might be overwritten by one or another

Comment: @NaveedButt I may be wrong, but it feels like if you have to use some sort of locking on the collection of primes anyway, it might be more efficient to use some kind of locking with your sum variable. I think you can use Interlocked.Add for that.

Comment: I have marked @samar's answer as correct one, because of using built in classes rather than implementing the lock myself